# How to parse RxJava to receive just the data that i want?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I just want the numbers, but this is what i'm receiving at log:

> [Boletim(grade=4.5), Boletim(grade=9.5)]

**The Response:**

```
public class GradeResponse {

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    MainPresenter mainPresenter;

    public void getGradeRx() {

        MyApplication.getMainComponent().injectIntoGradeResponse(this);// informando ao dagger sobre o uso de um component e a necessidade de injetar dependência

        Subscription getGrade = retrofit
                .create(GradeService.class)
                .getGrade()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(model -> {

                    return model.getBoletim();

                })
                .subscribe(new Observer<Boletim[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "saporra vai me matar ainda");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Boletim[] grades) {
                        Log.i(TAG, Arrays.asList(grades).toString());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**The models:**

*GradeModel:*

```
@SerializedName("boletim")
    @Expose
    private Boletim[] boletim;
```

*Boletim.class*

```
public class Boletim {

    @SerializedName("grade")
    @Expose
    private double grade;
```

The retrofit service is ok, the dependency injection is working. I'm receiving the onSuccess method from rxJava, i just need now receiving only the numbers without this **"[Boletim(grade="**.

Comment: See here for the flter operator - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables

Comment: You should not use `Arrays.asList(grades).toString()` then.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv what should i use then?

Comment: @StuStirling can u give an demonstration using that?

Comment: You don't need a list. `Arrays.toString(grades)`

Comment: @cricket_007 i did your way, and still same result.

Comment: Obviously... That didn't change anything

Comment: @StuStirling Why do you think this is a filter? It's a transformation

Comment: Correct, sorry read the question wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the toString of your objects because you get the entire object in your map!

> only the numbers without this "[Boletim(grade=".

Way can't you map again and extract it?

```
.map(model -> {               // This map returns a Boletim[]
     return model.getBoletim();
 })
.map(boletim -> {             // This map returns a double[]
    Double grades = new Double[boletim.length];
    for (int i =0; i < grades.length ; i++) {
        grades[i] = boletim[i].getGrade() ;
    } 
    return grades;
}).subscribe(new Observer<Double[]>() {   // This subscribes to a double[]
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "saporra vai me matar ainda");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Double[] grades) {
        Log.i(TAG, Arrays.toString(grades));
    }
}
```

Or you could put the for loop into onNext

If you don't want an Observable of arrays, then use flatMap

Comment: Didn't work. Because is saying "cannot solve the method subscribe".

Comment: And even if put inside the onNext dont work, because is needs a Boletim type, and that loop is for a double type.

Comment: 1) subscribe **is** a method, I didn't finish it because you already have it in your question 2) "*because is needs a Boletim type*" -- No, this is not true. I have mapped your `Boletim` object into a double array.  You need to change your code from `new Observer<Boletim[]>` to `new Observer<Double[]>`, as I have shown

Comment: I did this, and gave me an error again. Didnt accept the type

Comment: Alright, well, as I said, you could keep your current question's code and put the for-loop that extracts the grades inside of `onNext`

Comment: I did this too, and still. But i'll do different, i'll make some changes and try again. Later i comeback to say if worked. :D

Comment: That doesn't tell me what the error is... Try deleting it all, and putting `.subscribe` and let it auto-complete the rest

Comment: The error was cuz double[] is different than Double[]. lol thanks

Comment: No, it is new Observer<Double[]> but inside the map is                     Double[] grades = new Double[boletim.length];
I fixed your answer and gave to you the points. Thanks for the help, now is working like this [4.5, 9.5].

Comment: Strange. I've returned `int` types before, then it generates `Observable<Integer>`, so I assumed arrays would be the same, but guess not